# Flux through sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

I wish to find the flux of $\mathbf{F}=(x^2,y^2,z^2)$ through $S: (x-1)^2+(y-3)^2+(z+1)^2$

Here is what I tried:

I "moved" the sphere to $(0,0)$ by changing the variables to:

$u=x-1$ , $v=y-3$ , $w=z+1$

so now we have $F=((u+1)^2,(v+3)^2,(w-1)^2)$ and $S$ is the unit sphere.

So my calculation is (after switching to polar):

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}{\rm div}\,\mathbf{F}\,r\,{\rm d}z\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}(2r\cos\theta +2r\sin\theta +2z+6)r\,{\rm d}z\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta$$

but I got $0$ instead $8\pi$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your idea is right but miscaculation happens. Could you give more detail about calculation? BTW, here is what WA's done:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%5B(2xcos(y)%2B2xsin(y)%2B2z%2B6)x,%7Bx,0,1%7D,%7By,0,2pi%7D,%7Bz,-sqrt(1-x%5E2),sqrt(1-x%5E2)%7D%5D

Comment: @ZackNi thanks I found my mistake. thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One's procedure is excellent but there are some mistakes in your final calculation. Here is my way to compute the triple integral:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\left( 2r\cos\theta +2r\sin\theta +2z+6\right) r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta
&
 \stackrel{[A]}{=}\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\int_0^{2\pi}\left( 2r^2\cos\theta +2r^2\sin\theta +2rz+6r\right)\,d\theta \,dz\,dr
\\&
\stackrel{[B]}{=}\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\left( 4 \pi rz+12\pi r\right) \,dz\,dr
\\&
=\int_0^1\left.\left( 2 \pi rz^2+12\pi r z\right)\right| ^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}} \,dr 
\\ &
\stackrel{[C]}{=} \int_0^1\left( 24\pi r \sqrt{1-r^2}\right) \,dr 
\\&
=8\pi
\end{align}
$$

$[A]$ comes from [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).

$[B]$ comes from the linearity of integration.

$[C]$ comes from U-substitution.

Hopefully one can borrow some of strategies.

Comment: thank you! found my mistake too. great answer

Comment: @segevp You're very welcome :)

Comment: @zack Ni I edited your answer because I felt $\stackrel$ was what you wanted on your equal Signs. Feel free to roll back if you preferred the previous version.

Comment: @Lonidard I really appreciate your editting. I would change my format to a right one if I encounter a problem similar to it.

Answer (score 4):

To pass to spherical coordinates you do as  follows
$$2 (u+v+w+3)\quad u= r \cos (\phi) \sin (\theta),v= r \sin (\phi) \sin (\theta),w= r \cos (\theta)$$
and don't forget the Jacobian $r^2 \sin\theta$

$\int_0^{2 \pi } \left(\int_0^{\pi } \left(\int_0^1 2 r^2 \sin (\theta) (r \sin (\phi) \sin (\theta)+r \cos (\phi) \sin (\theta)+r \cos (\theta)+3) \, dr\right) \, dt\right) \, d\phi=8\pi$

Answer (score 2):

thanks to zack I found my miscalculation:

from where i stopped:
$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}divFrdzdrd\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}(2r\cos\theta +2r\sin\theta +2z+6)rdzdrd\theta=
\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}[r(2r\sin\theta-2r\cos\theta+(2z+6)\theta]_0^{2\pi}=2\pi\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}2zr+6r=2\pi\int_0^1[rz^2+6rz]_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}=2\pi\int_0^112r\sqrt{1-r^2}=[-4(1-r^2)]_0^1=8\pi$